# Querying a list in mongoengine; contains vs in

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a ListField in a model with ids (ReferenceField), and I need to do a query if a certain id is in that list. AFAIK I have 2 options for this:

```
Model.objects.filter(refs__contains='59633cad9d4bc6543aab2f39')
```

or:

```
Model.objects.filter(refs__in=['59633cad9d4bc6543aab2f39'])
```

Which one is the most efficient for this use case?

The model looks like:

```
class Model(mongoengine.Document):
    refs = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.ReferenceField(SomeOtherModel))
```

From what I can read in the mongoengine [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#string-queries), `contains` is really a string query, but it works surprisingly here as well. But I'm guessing that `__in` is more efficient since it should be optimized for lists, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The string queries normally under the covers are all regex query so would be less efficient.  However, the exception is when testing against reference fields! The following queries are:

```
Model.objects.filter(refs__contains="5305c92956c02c3f391fcaba")._query
{'refs': ObjectId('5305c92956c02c3f391fcaba')}
```

Which is a direct lookup.

```
Model.objects.filter(refs__in=["5305c92956c02c3f391fcaba"])._query
{'refs': {'$in': [ObjectId('5305c92956c02c3f391fcaba')]}}
```

This probably is less efficient, but would probably be extremely marginal.  The biggest impact would be the number of docs and whether or not the `refs` field has an index.